# How do you change a bubblesort algorithm to selection sort?

Tags: pseudocode

I've been trying to change my bubblesort algorithm to selection sort but I am struggling.

Here's the bubble sort...

```
For K= 0 to n â€“ 2 
For j = 0 to n â€“ k - 2
If item[j] > item [j + 1]
temp = item[j]
item[j] = item[j+1]
item[j + 1] = temp
end if
end for 
end for
end bubbleSort
```

Here's what a friend gave me in javascript and I was wondering if someone could help turn it into pseudo code? Thanks ...

```
var arr = new Array(23, 19, 35, 12, 30);
temp = 0;

for (k = 0; k < arr.length - 1; k++) {

for (j = k + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {

if (arr[k] > arr[j]) {

temp = arr[k];
arr[k] = arr[j];
arr[j] = temp;
}
}
}

for (k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
alert(arr[k]);
```

Thanks everyone, I'm new to programming and algorithms just get me!

Comment: It is difficult to understand what your problem is. That JS snippet is as readable as any pseudocode to me. Perhaps if you specify exactly what you have problems understanding..?

Comment: I'm very very new to this kinda stuff. Basically I want to change the bubblesort algorithm I have up there to a selection sort algorithm. And I'm not really sure how.

Comment: You should probably get a tutor and/or a book. I learn effectively from trying lots of things and seeing how they work out. Maybe you could do that. You could maybe ask your tutor to show you how to check simple things in `python` or another REPL (ask your tutor). Later on, when you have the basic knowledge, you can come back here and ask specific, narrow questions :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pseudocode of selection sort:

```
A = array(23, 19, 35, 12, 30) // make an array
n = length(A)                 // array length
min = 0                       // minimum element index is 0

for j = 0 to n - 1 do         // go through array
   min = j                    // assume the minimum element is the first element

   for i = j + 1 to n do      // test elements behind j-th element
      if(A[i] < A[min]) then  // if any of those elements is smaller, it's the new minimum
         min = i
   end for

   if(min <> j) then          // swap the minimum element (min) with the current (j)
      tmp = A[j]
      A[j] = A[min]
      A[min] = tmp
end for
```